# How to get the yahoo's mediaplayer javascript to ignore certain file types?

Tags: javascript, web, mp3, media-player

Is there any way to restrict what types of files the yahoo mediaplayer plays? We don't want it to play flv files but we do want it to play MP3s.

**Background**

Yahoo provides a really nice browser based mp3 player in the form of a simple javascript include. It will find any link to media file on your web page and adds a nice little player for each file. http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/

We're using this for MP3 files on our site and it's working great but we also have a flv video file on there that we don't want it to handle as we're using the shadowbox.js to play it. But, the yahoo mediaplayer is also playing the audio from the flv so we're getting the audio doubled. So, we want to somehow set the player to ignore FLVs or only find MP3s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://yahoomediaplayer.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ) in the wiki:

> "How do I link to some of the audio files in a page but not all?"
>
> Put class="htrack" into the audio files that you want. 
>      Once any audio link has this, any audio link that doesn't have it will be skipped."